# Getting "remember" option to work with Firebase's authAnonymously

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase's [anonymous authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/anonymous.html) to store data about users who visit my site. But I'm having trouble getting it to work as described.

Here's a simplified snippet of the relevant code:

```
var firebase_root = new Firebase('https://example.firebaseio.com');

firebase_root.authAnonymously(function(error, authData) {
    var page = firebase_root.child(uid).push(); // create a unique reference for this pageload

    page.child('loaded_page').set(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    page.child('left_page').onDisconnect().set(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
});
```

In the docs for anonymous authentication, it says

> If not specified - or set to default - sessions are persisted for as long as you have configured in the Login & Auth tab of your Firebase's Dashboard.

I've set my `Session Length` to 12 months in my settings so I would expect that if I load this page and then refresh the page I would get a structure like this:

```
{
    someRandomUserId: {
        randomPageId_1: {
            loaded_page: timestamp_1,
            left_page: timestamp_2
        },
        randomPageId_2: {
            loaded_page: timestamp_3
        }
    }
}
```

But it looks like it is actually re-assigning the user ID rather than persisting it across page loads. So I'm actually getting a structure like this:

```
{
    someRandomUserId_1: {
        randomPageId_1: {
            loaded_page: timestamp_1,
            left_page: timestamp_2
        }
    },
    someRandomUserId_2: {
        randomPageId_2: {
            loaded_page: timestamp_3
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a new authentication session each and every time you invoke `FirebaseRef.authAnonymously(...)`. This method only needs to be invoked once, after which the user will authenticated upon page refreshes.

If you'd like to check for the current authentication state of the user, and *only then* create a new authentication session if the user is not currently authenticated, use the synchronous accessor for authentication state `FirebaseRef.getAuth()`.